# DDOS Attack detection with netstat

Tags: ddos, netstat

I have a server, today load of my server over 20, i was found a command that detect alive connection to server for DDOS detection and reject IP.

```
netstat -anp | grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

and result of this command was:

```
  1 109.162.158.160
  1 109.162.192.55
  1 127.0.0.1
  1 206.217.193.220
  1 91.99.170.69
  2 66.197.219.236
  5 213.152.172.169
 32 0.0.0.0
583
```

583 connection without IP, how can i fix this problem? server load over 20

tnx for your help.

Comment: When you say "how can I fix this promlem?" Do you mean, the problem of being DDoS'ed or for actively monitoring of it?

Answer (score 7):

**It probably wasn't a dDOS attack with that small a level of connected IPs.**

The final line represents the output from `netstat -anp` where there is no foreign address actually defined. If the port is not yet established, the port number is shown as an asterisk (*) - likely UDP ports.

There are a lot of handy one-liner netstat commands to evaluate connections

#### Show number of connections by state

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

#### Show all IPs connected

```
netstat -nat | awk '{ print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' | uniq
```

#### Show number of connections per IP

```
netstat -atun | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

*Referenced from [Cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/netstat-command-tutorial-examples.html)*